# r - Shiny+leaflet: How to set Markers color depend on user input

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I added points on a map using shiny and leaflet. 
Each point is a different type of transit option.
I want to distinguish the different types by color and couldn't figure this out.
Tried using "if" which doesn't work.
Thanks!

This is the basic code I have

```
library(leaflet)
ui <- fluidPage(
leafletOutput("map"),
headerPanel("Example"),
sidebarPanel(checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "Type", label = "Data 
Layer",choices = c("Bike", "Muni", "Bus", "BART"), selected = "Bike")))

server <- function(input, output) {
output$map <- renderLeaflet({

rownumber = which(Stops_and_stations$Type == input$Type)
x <- Stops_and_stations[rownumber,]

leaflet(width = 1000, height = 500) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lng = x$stop_lon,
                   lat = x$stop_lat,
                   radius= 3, color = '#ff6633') %>% 
  setView(lng = -122.4000,
          lat = 37.79500,
          zoom = 13)
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And this is what I tried to add
     .....

```
 if(input$Type == "Bike"){

leaflet(width = 1000, height = 500) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lng = x$stop_lon,
                   lat = x$stop_lat,
                   radius= 3, color = '#ff6633') %>% 
  setView(lng = -122.4000,
          lat = 37.79500,
          zoom = 13)
}

if(input$Type == "Muni"){

leaflet(width = 1000, height = 500) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lng = x$stop_lon,
                   lat = x$stop_lat,
                   radius= 3, color = '#0033ff') %>% 
  setView(lng = -122.4000,
          lat = 37.79500,
          zoom = 13)
}
```

.....

Comment: we don't have access to Stops_and_stations$Type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier to answer to your question if you provided `Stops_and_stations` and thus made it a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)..

One approach to use distinct colors for different groups is to add a `color` column to your `data.frame`:

Since we don't know your data, I created some random dataset.

```
Stops_and_stations <- data.frame(
  Type = rep(c("Bike", "Muni", "Bus", "BART"), each = 10),
  stop_lon = -runif(40, 122.4200, 122.4500),
  stop_lat = runif(40, 37.76800, 37.78900),
  color = rep(c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"), each = 10)
)
```

Then instead of specifying a concrete color such as `#ff6633`, you can use the `color` column.

```
addCircleMarkers(lng = x$stop_lon,
                       lat = x$stop_lat,
                       radius= 3, color = x$color)
```

I would also like to point out that your subsetting is not right: you are using `checkboxGroupInput` which can have more values, so you need to use the `%in%` operator to filter.

```
x <- Stops_and_stations[Stops_and_stations$Type %in% input$Type,]
```